# Как правильно писать: "атом-класс" или "атомкласс"?

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать "атом-класс" или "атомкласс"? Речь идет о создании в школах специальных профильных классов при поддержке ГК "Росатом".

Answer (score 1):

О **правильном** написании в строгом смысле здесь речи идти не может: слово не зафиксировано словарями. Однако рекомендации дать могу. Насколько я понимаю, *атом-класс* – сложное слово с несклоняемой первой частью, выраженной существительным в им. п. ед. ч. с нулевым окончанием, и образовано оно по той же модели, что и, к примеру, *интернет-проект, рок-группа, онлайн-опрос* и подоб. Поэтому можно рекомендовать дефисное написание. Пишущие это слово слитно, вероятно, полагают его сложносокращённым словом, образованным по модели *стенгазета, загранпаспорт, хозтовары.* Мне эта версия представляется менее убедительной, однако если всё же считать существительное *атомкласс* сокращением сочетания *атомный класс,* то писать его нужно слитно. Таким образом, если вы хорошо понимаете, как образовано это слово, то и с написанием затруднений не возникнет.